# Transmission is failed to start due the weird file permissions

Tags: raspbian

I have problems with starting of transmission-daemon:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/mnt/store $ sudo systemctl start transmission-daemon
Job for transmission-daemon.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status transmission-daemon.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and it happens because it's unable to read settings.json due weird permissions:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/mnt/store $ ls -la /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
--w------- 1 debian-transmission debian-transmission 2333 May 25 15:27 /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

When I change the permission to "wr" for the file transmission starts, but `settings.json` is getting only "w" permission again and I need to change the permission manually again.

How to fix the issue and be able to start transmission every time automatically?

**UPD:**

The output of "journalctl -xe" regarding transmission

```
-- The job identifier is 1095.
May 26 10:34:08 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[2265]: [2021-05-26 10:34:08.205] Couldn't read "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json": Permission denied
May 26 10:34:08 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[2265]: [2021-05-26 10:34:08.207] transmission-daemon Error loading config file -- exiting. (daemon.c:693)
May 26 10:34:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit transmission-daemon.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
May 26 10:34:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-
```

**UPD2**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ls -la /var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Aug 31  2020 /var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json -> /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

Comment: what's the output of `journalctl -xe` regarding `transmission-daemon`

Comment: I have updated the question. It complains on wrong permissions for `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` as I said in my question

Comment: looks more like `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json` ... but maybe I can't read

Comment: It's still same file. I have update the question one more time. Sorry for pulling the info from me. I really appreciate willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found the reason.

It's happening if I change `umask` field in the `setting.json` to 777.

If I make `"umask": 0` then the permissions stops to be changed.

Weird :-/ but this is how it works, change umask - have issues, revert changes - no issues. Tried 5 times.

P.S. Also, good to know that transmission expects `umask` as a decimal notation, so 777 does not make sense for it.